# Representations of $\mathfrak{gl}(N)$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Suppose I have a finite-dimensional highest weight representation $V$ of $\mathfrak{gl}(N)$ with highest weight $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_N)$, ie there exists a vector $v\in V$ such that $$E_{ij}v=0, \quad 1\leq i<j\leq N$$$$E_{ii}v=\lambda_i v,\quad i=1,\dots,N$$

What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for the V to also be a finite-dimensional $GL(N)$ representation?

Comment: You have accepted an answer that is incorrect. Please read my comments to the answer below.

Comment: @Okazaki : I'm sorry that I gave a wrong answer, I was not familiar enough with the subject and I wrote what I remembered. I'll be more careful next time.